# Why does my picture with curved borders go square on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling

It works in most situations. My needs should look like this:

[image: working]

I have a section where I want to show a few needs in one row and scroll horizontally. When I try to set display: flex on the parent div (or white-space: nowrap and display: inline-block so I can use overflow-x: scroll, etc...) I get something more like this:

[image: failing]

Here's some simplified test HTML:

```
<section id="needs" class="row">
  <h2>Needs</h2>
  <div id="needs-wrapper">
    <!--<need *ngFor="let need of lastNeeds" [need]="need"></need> (full ng2 component used for below images)-->
    <div class="test-need">
      <section class="needSecTest">
        <div class="imgwrapper">
          <img class="cover-image" src="assets/images/donate.jpg" alt="Cover Image">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="test-need">
      <section class="needSecTest">
        <div class="imgwrapper">
          <img class="cover-image" src="assets/images/explore.jpg" alt="Cover Image">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="test-need">
      <section class="needSecTest">
        <div class="imgwrapper">
          <img class="cover-image" src="assets/images/electric_arc.jpg" alt="Cover Image">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And I got CSS for 'ya

```
#needs {
    background-color: #CDDC39;
    color: #757575;
    /*padding: 35px 20px;*/
    height: 700px;
}
#needs-wrapper{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: flex;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}
.test-need{
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
#cover-image{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.imgwrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    background: #c1c1c1;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0 !important;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.needSecTest {
    width: 286px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

The problem only happens on mobile. When I figured this at first I thought it was a problem with Chrome Dev. Tools (god knows there's enough of them) but then I deployed to a test server and opened on my phone and sure enough, square images... so actually kudos to Google for showing the bug in dev. tools!

At the request of commentators I created a jsfiddle BUT it does not reproduce the problem, even if you use Chrome Dev. Tools to simulate mobile. It only happens in a native browser (tested with Chrome) on or simulating mobile. In any case, here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Methodician/fLvjum5b/

And why not. Here's the test site on a server (will be updated or removed as time passes): https://aid2assist-dev.firebaseapp.com/home

Scroll down to the green needs section and go to mobile on dev tools (or open on your phone) and the bug appears...

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Your code sample does nothing for us. Raw (no angluar) html would be better. Perhaps you could even put it in a fiddle and send a link.

Comment: Drop `white-space: nowrap` and `display: inline-block` and add `display: flex;` to the `#need-wrapper` rule

Comment: can u make a jsfiddle. with no angular please. makes it easier to see what is not working, also try adding !important to the border-radius, in case you are overwriting it by mistake

Comment: You guys are totally right. Sorry. Hurried Late-night Stack Overflow posts can go poorly.

Comment: @LGSon that's an easier and less convoluted way to get at the same scroll effect. Thanks! However, it does not change the problem, so I'll remove the Angular and maybe create a jsfiddle...

Comment: OOoooookay That was just nuts. For a while there I even thought the bug disappeared but nope - use a mobile browser or set the dev tools in Chrome to simulate one and the bug reappears. Fun stuff! Thanks for your comments and the guidance/push... I really want this to work! I think the site could make a difference in the world and my client is very dedicated.